# How to loop through array and change its item

Tags: python

i'm looping through an array and changing its item by a random number between 1 and 10

```
from time import sleep as wait
from os import system as sys
import random
memory = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

def cls(): sys("cls")

def main():
    for i in memory:
        memory[i] = random.randrange(1,10)
        print(memory)
        wait(0.1)
        cls()
    print("OK")
    input("")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but it only changes the first item of the array

how can i fix this?

Comment: You are using the _values_ of `memory`, so you are repeatedly changing `memory[0]`, as many time as you have `0` in the array. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: As an aside, the wait and clearing the screen at the end are horrible ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your for loop :

```
for i in range(len(memory)):
```

in your for each loop i always 0 and you refers to first element ..

Answer (score 0):

Because your `i` is always `0`. And you change only the first element. 
I also replaced your class method, by print() parameters. 
Please try this snippet:

```py
from time import sleep as wait
import random

memory = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]


def main():
    for i, item in enumerate(memory):
        item = random.randrange(1,10)
        memory[i] = item
        print(memory, end="\r", flush=True)
        wait(0.1)
    print("OK")
    input("")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is effecient for your case. but it can achieve the output you want.

```
from time import sleep as wait
from os import system as sys
import random

memory = [0 for _ in range(0, 29)]

def cls(): sys("cls")

def main():
    global memory
    for _ in memory:        
        ran_index = random.randrange(1, 29)
        memory[ran_index] = random.randrange(1,10)
        print(memory)
        memory = [0 for _ in range(0, 29)]
        wait(0.1)
        cls()
    print("OK")
    input("")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop:

```
for i in memory:
```

Has `i` represent each element of the array in turn. All of those elements are `0`.

Thus:

```
memory[i] = random.randrange(1,10)
```

Only ever assigns to the first element in `memory`.

To iterate over the *indices* of `memory`:

```
for i in range(len(memory)):
```

But really, if you just want 29 random numbers on a list, a list comprehension will do that jobh much more cleanly.

```
memory = [random.randrange(1,10) for _ in range(29)]
```